# How is this R function returning a value?

Tags: r

I have the following R code:

```
n <- 100
simul <- function() {
  x <- sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE)
  s <- cumsum(c(0, x))
}
(tmp = simul())
```

In the above code, `simul()` returns a vector to `tmp`. How is this possible, since the function `simul()` does *not* define any return value (at least, explicitly)?

Comment: you are assigning `<-` or `=` to an identifier and here the `.Last.value` from 's' is passed on to it

Comment: Ahh, I see. What is `.Last.Value`? Is there any documentation that explains this (I haven't encountered any mention of this)?

Comment: You can test it by adding one more line `s1 <- 'hello'` at the end of the function and see what happens.  The `.Last.value` i meant is the last line of code evaluated

Comment: Tried it and it was as you said. Is this mentioned in the r documentation?

Comment: @akrun That question doesn't really address the same point in a direct and clear way.

Comment: I guess the question is similar to the one you mentioned.  If I quote the answer `By default, a function returns the value of the last expression evaluated,`. What do you expect as an answer here?

Comment: From https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/function : *If the end of a function is reached without calling `return`, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.*

Comment: @akrun yes, I understand now. Thank you for the clarification.